# Can I start a coroutine in `ViewModel.onCleared()`?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I want the data to be saved to a file when the viewmodel is destroyed, here is the code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) :
  ViewModel() {

  private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow("jack")
  val uiState: StateFlow<String> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
  @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
  override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    // Writing data to a file
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
      val file = File(context.filesDir, "name.json")
      val outputStream = file.outputStream()
      outputStream.use {
        _uiState.collect { value ->
          Json.encodeToStream(value, outputStream)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. By doing this, I lose the reference to the job object, does this follow `structured concurrency`?
2. Should the code for storing data come before or after the parent method `super.onCleared()`?
3. Will this code run successfully?
4. If I start a coroutine using `viewModelScope.launch()`, will the coroutine run successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In this case it's fine, since you don't have any condition under which you would want to cancel this coroutine. But since using `CoroutineScope(IO).launch` is a common anti-pattern, I suggest using `GlobalScope.launch(IO)` with `@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)` to indicate you are intentionally doing it.
2. Doesn't matter.
3. Yes, it will write the file unless there's an IO exception. However, you are leaking the StateFlow and the OutputStream forever because `collect` called on a SharedFlow or StateFlow never returns.
4. Most likely not, but it's a race condition. `encodeToStream` is not interruptible. If that line of code is reached before the `viewModelScope` is cancelled, then it will succeed in writing, but if it doesn't, then it won't.

You should change your code as follows to prevent the leak:

```
  @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
  @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
  override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    // Writing data to a file
    GlobalScope.launch(IO) {
      val file = File(context.filesDir, "name.json")
      try {
        file.outputStream().use { outputStream ->
          Json.encodeToStream(uiState.value, outputStream)
        }
      } catch(e: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write ui state", e)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why does it cause leaks? What is `StateFlow` being held by, the `IO` thread?

Comment: It's not a thread; it's a coroutine, but yes, it's held by the coroutine. A launched coroutine captures references to everything it uses until it completes. This is why you rarely need GlobalScope, and using `CoroutineScope().launch` to avoid the GlobalScope warning is an anti-pattern. There are few situations where you would want to allow a coroutine to run forever, because of memory and resource leaks. However, since you want to do nothing but write a file and have no reason to cancel it, this case is an exception. But you can't use `collect { }` or the coroutine will never complete.

Comment: By "run forever" I meant run until it finishes completely. Just like a started Thread, a launched coroutine runs until completion (either finishing or getting cancelled) even if you are not holding a reference to its Job or CoroutineScope.